# JavaScript Dropdown Function Refactor

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Hey guys I have 3 dropdown's, each one has its own `id`, I do this because I set the value of the dropdown to whichever I choose and I want to differentiate between them.

The html for my dropdowns is:

```
<div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="make" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Subject
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="makein">
                    <li>bmw</li>
                    <li>mercedes</li>
                    <li>mazda</li>
                    <li>ford</li>
                    <li>lada</li>
                    <li>audi</li>
                    <li>skoda</li>
                    <li>fiat</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="year" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Year
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="yearin">
                    <li>2016</li>
                    <li>2015</li>
                    <li>2014</li>
                    <li>2013</li>
                    <li>2012</li>
                    <li>2011</li>
                    <li>2010</li>
                    <li>2009</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="level" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Level
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="levelin">
                    <li>luxury</li>
                    <li>ordinary</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

I have 3 JavaScript functions to set the value of the dropdown for each section based on their id as follows:

```
$(function () {
        $("#makein li").click(function(){

            $("#make").html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');

        });
    });

$(function () {
        $("#yearin li").click(function(){

            $("#year").html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');

        });
    }); 

$(function () {
        $("#levelin li").click(function(){

            $("#level").html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');

        });
    });
```

I really don't like the approach having the 3 different JavaScript functions. I was wondering if you guys know a way around making these 3 functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```js
  $(function() {
    $("li").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().siblings('button').first().html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="make" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Subject
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>  
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="makein">
    <li>bmw</li>
    <li>mercedes</li>
    <li>mazda</li>
    <li>ford</li>
    <li>lada</li>
    <li>audi</li>
    <li>skoda</li>
    <li>fiat</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="year" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Year
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="yearin">
    <li>2016</li>
    <li>2015</li>
    <li>2014</li>
    <li>2013</li>
    <li>2012</li>
    <li>2011</li>
    <li>2010</li>
    <li>2009</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="level" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Level
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="levelin">
    <li>luxury</li>
    <li>ordinary</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu li').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('dropdown').find('button').html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>')
  })
})
```

Comment: With this one, whenever you choose any 1 of the options from the drop down, the entire dropdown is populated with all of the dropdown options.

Comment: @Gothdo $(this) in your example refers to the whole ul so the button contains the text of all the list items of the ul that was clicked on.

Comment: My desire is to only populate it with the chosen value, not all of the values.